# Linear mapping in the vector space of real polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

I am struggling with this:

Let $$V = \{ \sum_{j=0}^{4} c_jx^j:c_0,...,c_j \in \mathbb{R} \} $$  be the vector space of real polynomials with degree <= four and let $$U = \{ \sum_{j=0}^{3} c_jx^j:c_0,...,c_j \in \mathbb{R} \} $$ be the vector space of real polynomials with degree <= three.

Determine the display matrix o the linear map $f : U \rightarrow V, f(P)(x) = (3 − x)P(x)$

regarding the Bases $A= (1, x, x^2, x^3)$ of U and $B=(1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4)$ of V

How do I produce The Images of the base vectors. I dont even know how to interprete the linear map $f$

Please be kind, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f : U \rightarrow V$, such that $f(P(x)) = (3 − x)P(x)$, then
$$\begin{cases}
&f(1)=(3-x)(1)=3-x;\\
&f(x)=(3-x)(x)=3x-x^2;\\
&f(x^2)=(3-x)(x^2)=3x^2-x^3;\\
&f(x^3)=(3-x)(x^3)=3x^3-x^4.\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you, i can work with that.